# Unable to read Vault secrets - using Vault Sidecar Injector

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, hashicorp-vault

Unable to read the secrets stored in Vault at path /secrets/apims/ABC_CONFIG using below setup

Policy created in Vault:

```
  vault policy write policy_name - <<EOF
    path "secret/apims/*" {
      capabilities = ["read"]
    }
```

Role created in Vault

```
vault write auth/kubernetes/role/role_name\
    bound_service_account_names=service_account_name \
    bound_service_account_namespaces=default \
    policies=policy_name \
    ttl=24h
```

Using Kubernetes vault sidecar injector over the external vault. The deployment on Kubernetes looks like

```yaml
apiVersion: "apps/v1"
kind: "Deployment"
metadata:
  name: "nginx-5"
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: "nginx-5"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "nginx-5"
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations: 
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-credentials.conf: secret/ABC_CONFIG
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: role_name
      labels:
        app: "nginx-5"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "nginx-5"
        image: "nginx:latest"
      serviceAccountName: service_account_name
```

Though Kubernetes is successfully authorized with Vault, reading specific keys fails with 403.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like neither the service account nor the role name defined in the Vault role matches the ones in the deployment.

- Service Account = service_account_name
- Role = role_name

```
vault write auth/kubernetes/role/role_name\
    bound_service_account_names=service_account_name \
    bound_service_account_namespaces=default \
    policies=policy_name \
    ttl=24h
```

- Service Account = sa-vault-auth
- Role = apims

```yaml
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "nginx-5"
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations: 
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-credentials.conf: secret/ABC_CONFIG
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: apims 
      labels:
        app: "nginx-5"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "nginx-5"
        image: "nginx:latest"
      serviceAccountName: sa-vault-auth 
...
```

This is also assuming that `policies=policy_name` is the name of the policy that you created in Vault initially.

Comment: it was my mistake forgot to scrub the changed name in question for kubernetes deployment file, but I am using the same roles/policy and serviceAccount in all the places. Still its thorwing same error.

I will also update the question, thanks.

Comment: do you find anything else which might create issues?

Comment: I didn't really, it has to be a mismatch of names somewhere.